# Are agreements between different powers binding?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Currently, the Alliance and the Sirius Corporation are under an [Inter-faction Mutual Benefit Agreement](https://community.elitedangerous.com/galnet/uid/55a3dbe09657ba992d3de737). The agreement states that members of both powers will support each other where mutual profit is to be had, and in action against mutual enemies.

Is this sort of agreement binding? That is, will a Sirius Corporation ship show up as an enemy in Alliance space, or will that ship show up as clean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, those agreements are not binding. It's more a Role-Playing Advice.

The game engine doesn't know about those agreements. A Sirius ship is labeled as 'enemy' to everyone pledged to another power.

However, your ship is also labeled as 'Sirius' - or whatever power you pledged to - so the other commander can adjust his/her reaction. If she knows about the agreement and decides to honor it, you might be fine.

Comment: Given that I just flew through Patreus space as an ALD pledged pilot without being flagged as hostile... I think this warrants some review. Same major faction may just be an exception, but clearly it isn't as simple as "the game engine doesn't care at all"

Comment: @Unionhawk I didn't say "Hostile", I said "Enemy". Stations will not shoot at you for being an enemy, so you can dock and trade. But players and NPCs can attack you without being fined. And if you fire back at them, you will be fined for attacking clean targets.

Comment: "Hostile" is the little red flag that comes up when you're in enemy power space, where "Wanted" or "Illicit Cargo" shows up that warns you of your current status - I'm saying that I didn't show up as an enemy in Patreus space. So at a minimum, powers in the same major faction seem to show up as clean.